# Why ajax.reload on datatable disables the buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

When I used ajax.reload on datatable then it disables the button from the data table.

Why? I am using it to reload the new data into datatable. But it disables the buttons. Why this is happening? How to fix it?

```
$('#tblPartySalesReport').DataTable.ajax.reload(null, false)({

                    bPaginate: false,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [

                        {
                            text: 'Party Report',
                            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                             window.location.href=   "@Url.Action("ServicesDetailedReportPartyWise", "DetailedServicesReport")";
                            }
                        },
                         {
                             text: 'Expenses Report',
                             action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                 window.location.href=   "@Url.Action("ExpensesReport", "Expenses")";
                             }
                         },
           'copyHtml5',
           'excelHtml5',
           'csvHtml5',
           {
               extend: 'pdfHtml5',
               footer: true,
               title: 'Closing Report (' + $('#FromDate').val() + ' - ' + $('#ToDate').val() + ')',
               customize: function (doc) {
                   doc.styles.title = {
                       color: 'gray',
                       fontSize: '15',
                       alignment: 'center'
                   }

                   doc.content[1].table.widths =
                       Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');

                   doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 10;
                   doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left';
                   doc.styles.tableHeader.color = 'white'
               }
           },
           {
               extend: 'print',
               footer: true
               //title: 'Sales Report'
           }

                    ]
                });
            }
```

Comment: Why do you repeat the buttons definition in the `ajax.reload()` call? Have you tried to left it out? You only need to declare the buttons once.

Comment: I had similar problem and the solution was to add 'l' to dom property. Try "Blfrtip".